# Identity Server does not call BackChannelLogout urls

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, identityserver4, identityserver3

I am trying to implement Single Sign Out pattern with Identity Server but it doesn't work so far. What I have been doing is, of course, registering BackChannelLogout url for each client registered in my Identity Server. According to the manual (http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/signout.html) , the Back-channel server-side methodology works in such a way that all the clients with a BackChannelLogout url registered receive an http request with a logout token.
This unfortunately doesn't happen. By checking out samples of this pattern, I see they keep pointing to this part of code:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> BackChannelLogout(string logout_token)
{
        Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store");
        Response.Headers.Add("Pragma", "no-cache");

        try
        {
            var user = await ValidateLogoutToken(logout_token);

            // these are the sub & sid to signout
            var sub = user.FindFirst("sub")?.Value;
            var sid = user.FindFirst("sid")?.Value;

            return Ok();
        }
        catch { }

        return BadRequest();
}
```

I see however no sign that directly points to these specific http requests towards the registered clients. How does this work? Can you please point me to the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: I checked the source code and it looks at a glance that the only time when `BackChannelLogoutClient` is used is when `/endsession/callback/` endpoint is called on the identity server. So basically out of the box, this doesn't happen with quickstart account controller and views as far as I can see.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius That's correct indeed. Found a guide explaining what's going on behind the scene. Will post it as answer if someone else has the same problem I had.

Comment: Just for the future lost souls - [great answer with all the code needed, which works for me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57785180/409257)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that **endession/callback** endpoint is the one responsible for calling all the urls registered as **BackChannelLogout**. The **Logout** controller is the one responsible for the whole pipeline. Detailed guide here, hope it helps others with my same problem!
https://blog.tretainfotech.com/posts/2018/August/single-sign-out-in-identityserver4-with-back-channel-logout

Comment: Please include some of the code from the page you have linked.  Enough to show the solution.  Link only anwsers are not helpful if the site goes down.

Comment: @Tarta, thanks for that.  I was hoping  that it will help me - I have a similar config, it used to work and without a change it is now not even hitting the logout endpoint... I will study your blog entry, maybe there is a clue.

Comment: @vt100 no problem and hope it helps!